# I'm having trouble getting my array formula to work in sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, spreadsheet

```
 =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERROR(INDEX('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$E$67,SMALL(IF('AE Worksheet'!$F$1:$F$67<'AE Worksheet'!$A$3,ROW('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$67)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$E$67,SMALL(IF('AE Worksheet'!$F$1:$F$67<'AE Worksheet'!$A$3,ROW('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$67)),ROW(1:1)),2))), 1, 1)
```

Column F are dates and A3 is a date.  I do have dates in column F that are previous to the date in A3 but the formula is not returning anything.  This formula will work but will only return those that are 1 day prior to the date, I want to see all prior to the date.

```
 =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERROR(INDEX('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$E$67,SMALL(IF('AE Worksheet'!$F$1:$F$67='AE Worksheet'!$A$3-1,ROW('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$67)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$E$67,SMALL(IF('AE Worksheet'!$F$1:$F$67='AE Worksheet'!$A$3-1,ROW('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$67)),ROW(1:1)),2))), 1, 1)
```

Comment: Your title says Sheets but you've tagged Excel... which program are you using?

Comment: I'm working in google sheets

Answer (score -1):

> This formula will work but will only return those that are 1 day prior to the date, I want to see all prior to the date.

Remove the array constrain:

```
       =(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERROR(INDEX('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$E$67,SMALL(IF('AE Worksheet'!$F$1:$F$67='AE Worksheet'!$A$3-1,ROW('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$67)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$E$67,SMALL(IF('AE Worksheet'!$F$1:$F$67='AE Worksheet'!$A$3-1,ROW('AE Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$67)),ROW(1:1)),2))))
```

Comment: Click the ✔ on the left of this post to mark this as solved.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the formula. Without actual data access  or even a dummy data with the same reproducible problem, it's not possible to debug this.